# Substituting cells with only a space value with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

Original data-set is handfilled. This results in users adding a space to an otherwise blank cell. Looking for a way to substitute this cell with a blank cell.

Been trying TRIM in formula-form as well as VBA and these don't seem to hit the spot. Also have been trying Replace spaces with nothing, but this also removes spaces that are in text values.

```
Sub CleanKlussen()
    Worksheets("WorkSheetX").Select
    Range("AC2").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            cell.Value = Trim(cell)
        Next cell
End Sub
```

For a selected range on a selected sheet I would like to have all cells that only contain 1 or 2 spaces (no other value whatsoever) substituded by nothing (creating an empty cell).

Comment: you can use `range("a1").offset(0,columns.count).End(xlToLeft)` and `range("a1").offset(rows.count,0).End(xlUp)`  to select the range, or `usedrange`

Comment: Firstly, try avoiding the use of things like `Select` or `Activate` in VBA, they serve no purpose. In your `FOR` loop, try something like: `If Len(Trim(cell.Value)) = 0 Then`. If it is, replace it with an empty cell

Comment: Be aware that your "spaces" may be a simple space like `If .Value = " "` or a non-breaking space like `If .Value = CHR(160)`. The latter can not be "trimmed" simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Selection
    If Len(WorksheetFunction.Trim(c.Value2)) = 0 Then c.ClearContents
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

or another approach, loop the following until nothing is found

```
    dim r as excel.range

    set r = Range("A1:C3").Find(What:=" ", After:=Range("a1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
            :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False)
   r.clearcontents
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure not to `trim` numeric values, else they will be converted to strings.

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Dim v As Variant
    v = cell.Value2
    If Not IsNumeric(v) Then
        v = Trim(v)
        If v = "" Then
            cell.ClearContents
        Else
            cell.Value2 = v
        End If
    End If
Next cell
```

N.B. Get rid of all these useless `Select`-statements in your code.